# How do i sets GetRolesAsync to string model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1

I Have string model in my viewmodel i want to convert GetRolesAsync  to string.

```
var string = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(item);
```

>
'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'string'

Comment: Hello, firstly you need to change your variable name as "string" is a reserved keyword and secondly are you passing an application user?

Comment: hello.
i know, its only example for string var.
i want to find user role and set string var in my view model.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
var rolename = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(model);
        user1.RoleName = rolename[0].ToString();
```

Its works fine for me.

Comment: GetRolesAsync returns a list of roles the user belongs to. This example only deals with the first role returned. You can never be sure of the order things are returned either so if they do belong to more than one role then you might be ignoring the 'correct' one. Better to add a string array to your user class and assign them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = await _userManager.Users.Where(x => x.Id == request.UserId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (user != null)
            {
                Task<IList<string>> roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                var returnUser = _mapper.Map<AspNetUser, AspNetUserDto>(user);
                if (returnUser != null)
                {
                    if (roles != null && roles.Result != null)
                        returnUser.Roles = roles.Result.ToList();

                    return returnUser;
                }
            }
```